# What is the least verbose way to convert a Double to Data.Text?

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

How do I convert a Double to Data.Text?

In essence, I had the following code:

```
Data.Text.pack $ show 9.0
```

That code has some rather obvious silliness. So I dug around in the documentation and came up with this:

```
toStrict $ toLazyText $ realFloat 9.0
```

This seems better, but it seems like there should be a more direct method, but I can't find anything with type Double -> Data.Text. Is this the best way? It seems that if I switch to lazy Text I can avoid this, but I'm not quite ready to do that.

Any words of wisdom?

Comment: What's the problem with `pack . show`?

Comment: I was hoping there was a more efficient route from Double to Text. In reality (pack . show) is slightly faster than (toStrict . toLazyText . realFloat) but I'm sure I can get better performance if I keep everything in builders for longer.

Comment: I think the title is misleading as it gives the impression that Data.Text is a class. Hence, I changed it for you. You can rollback if you want, but I think this one is more clear.

Comment: @monadic: thanks. I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `printf` like package [text-format](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-format).

Answer (score 2):

[`ClassyPrelude`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/classy-prelude-0.8.0.1/docs/ClassyPrelude.html) provides a `Show` typeclass as mentioned in [Thomas' previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6449286/2597135).

See [`tshow`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/classy-prelude-0.8.0.1/docs/ClassyPrelude.html#v:tshow) and [`tlshow`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/classy-prelude-0.8.0.1/docs/ClassyPrelude.html#v:tlshow). The latter one produces a lazy text.

Note that the default implementation is just `T.fromList . Prelude.show`.

I recommend reading [the Yesod blog on ClassyPrelude](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2012/07/classy-prelude) for general information about that package. Note that it is not a drop-in replacement for the standard prelude.

Answer (score 1):

The tongue-in-cheek answer:

```
f :: Double -> Data.Text
f = Data.Text.pack . show
```

Then you simply use

```
f 9.0
```

Can't get much more terse than that, right? Don't be afraid to roll your own utility methods for convenience (though they should probably have more descriptive names than `f`). If you think it could be generally useful, then contact the maintainer.

Comment: Generally I'm not averse to rolling my own methods. I just don't know my way around the Haskell packages very well. For instance, @tibbe answer was what I was looking for, but I didn't remember text-format existed!